# Show other view on slide up android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am starting a new project in android.I have to make it like google maps.For example see the image below

[image]

The screen will be like this with 2 views.1st mark with red and other with yellow.
Now what i want is that when user drags view 2 from bottom to top it should be like this

[image]

How can i achieve this.Please do help me out as i new to andriod development
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Sorry but i dnot know where to start from

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar implementation in [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) library. Download the sample app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.samples2) and see the

- SlidingUpGridView
- SlidingUpListView
- SlidingUpRecyclerView
- SlidingUpScrollView
- SlidingUpWebView

options.

**EDIT**

Looks like [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) is a better solution.

**EDIT 2**

If you don't want to use that library, I suggest use the codes of that library. It's really not that much work.

1. Create a new package `sliderlib` or something in your project
2. Create two classes named `ViewDragHelper.java` and `SlidingUpPanelLayout.java`
3. Copy the contents of the two named classes [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/tree/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel)
4. Download [these](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/tree/master/library/res/drawable) drawables to your drawable directory of your app
5. Add [these](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml) values to your `attrs.xml` (create one if there isn't one)
6. And in your XML, use your new widget like this.

**your_layout.xml**

```
<your.app.package.sliderlib.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

    <!-- Your views to show in your Sliding Up Panel -->

</your.app.package.sliderlib.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

**NOTE** : **The answer may not be exactly right. But it will be a start.**

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir but i wanted to do it without library.Is there any way or code which can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library, probably this is what you want to achieve.